# Facebook API Search By Phone Number - Possible?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-php-sdk

Is there a way using Facebook API to search using a phone number, and pull back users name? I can't seem to find in the API a search using mobile feature? If you type a number into the Facebook search bar it will pull back the user if they have it assigned - so no extra permissions, I don't think.

Comment: Of course there is not

Comment: I only meant public information - I would of thought this would of just been like searching facebook username or something similiar

Comment: Just because you can find something on facebook.com doesn't mean it is available in the API